Data structure to order by sequence of appearance based on logical relationship?
I only have access to basic python. I do not have access to use DataFrames.
The problem scenario: When a ticket is opened, one or multiple files are checked out by the ticket, once the ticket is closed the files are released to be used by the next ticket. The goal is to determine the order of the tickets starting with the tickets that are delivered first. The sample list I have is:



file_path
file_version
ticket_name




path/to/file/A
2.2
t_43


path/to/file/A
2.3
t_21


path/to/file/B
1.1
t_256


path/to/file/B
1.2
t_43


path/to/file/B
1.3
t_21


path/to/file/B
1.4
t_20


path/to/file/C
5.7
t_30


path/to/file/C
5.8
t_20


path/to/file/D
3.3
t_21


path/to/file/D
3.4
t_50


path/to/file/D
3.5
t_40



By hand I would determine that the list order must be:
t_256
t_43
*(t_21 -> t_50 -> t_40)*
t_30
t_20

That is because I can see the relationship of t_256 is listed before t_43 in path/to/file/B group. So t_256 must have been delivered before t_43. I also see that t_30 is listed before t_20 in path/to/file/C group. so t_30 must have been delivered before t_20. Lastly I can see that t_50 and t_40 must have been delivered after t_21 since the only  is the only information we have in path/to/file/D group. I can not figure out how to code the sorting algorithm for this problem.
This must account for a large data set and must consider the tickets table could be listed in any order. For example:



file_path
file_version
ticket_name




path/to/file/A
2.2
t_43


path/to/file/A
2.3
t_21


path/to/file/D
3.3
t_21


path/to/file/D
3.4
t_50


path/to/file/D
3.5
t_40


path/to/file/C
5.7
t_30


path/to/file/C
5.8
t_20


path/to/file/B
1.1
t_256


path/to/file/B
1.2
t_43


path/to/file/B
1.3
t_21


path/to/file/B
1.4
t_20



The data set will be logically correct (there will always be an a correct order of ticket delivery). I need ideas as I can not think of a good data structure that can do this with big O in mind.
I tried to use the look ahead method but I am not sure how to accurately solve this issue.

How is the data stored? why not just use a dict for lookups based on path?

The data is stored in a dict, separated by paths. I just don't know the algorithm to sort the tickets based on the whole data not just each "group" of paths.

Please give a sample of the data in its dict form so that we can try and work out solutions ourselves

'''{
'path/to/file/A': [['path/to/file/A', '2.2', 't_43'], ['path/to/file/A', '2.3', 't_21']],
'path/to/file/B': [['path/to/file/B', '1.1', 't_256'], ['path/to/file/B', '1.2', 't_43'], ['path/to/file/B', '1.3', 't_21'], ['path/to/file/B', '1.4', 't_20']],
'path/to/file/C': [['path/to/file/C', '5.7', 't_30'], ['path/to/file/C', '5.8', 't_20']],
'path/to/file/D': [['path/to/file/D', '3.3', 't_21'], ['path/to/file/D', '3.4', 't_50'], ['path/to/file/D', '3.5', 't_40']]
}'''

The data already seems to be sorted -- what are you trying to output? Because you could just get the info directly from the dict if everything will be logically correct (I don't see any info conflicts that you have to deal with).

How do I create an ordered list of tickets in the order they are closed based on the relationships of each path group. I have the output in the description.
